# Combining three chart types Apex charts on Angular

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I would like to combine 3 chart types. How to get `Pulse` series to show on chart as scatter? When base `chart.type` is `line` it will not show. If it's changed to `scatter` for example, Pulse will show up but it also effectively disables lines. Desired end result is Pulse will show as scatter dots and other types stay as they are.

```json
        {
          name: "Income",
          type: "column",
          data: [1.4, 2, 0, 1.5, 2.5, 2.8, 3.8, 4.6]
        },
        {
          name: "Cashflow",
          type: "column",
          data: [0, 3, 3.1, 4, 4.1, 4.9, 6.5, 8.5]
        },
        {
          name: "Revenue",
          type: "line",
          data: [0, 0, 37, 36, 44, 45, 50, 58]
        }
        ,
        {
          name: "Pulse",
          type: "scatter",
          data: [10, 15, 37, 36, 44, 90, 50, 20]
        }
      ],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "line",
        stacked: false
      },
```

Here is the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-combo-multiple-yaxis-forked-x7okb?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Maybe it's how Apex charts works under the hood and some chart types cannot be combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scatter chart added with Line chart and Column chart.**

code - https://codesandbox.io/s/apex-chart-combine-three-xclhy

Output -

[image: apex-chart-combine-three]

Comment: Hello thanks for this! Do you know if change in data type to have x,y is the only way to include scatter? `{x:2009,y:5}` I guess scatter can't consume array of values e.g `[2, 3, 4 ...]`

Comment: The only way to include scatter is to put it in the first place of `series`. Actually single scatter accepts Array format like [[11,22], [...]] but when Scatter combine with others then it will accepts [{x:2009,y:5}, {...}].